# Find order of the given permutation

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let $\sigma$ be the permutation:
$$1 \quad2 \quad3 \quad4 \quad5 \quad6\quad 7\quad 8\quad 9$$
$$3\quad 5 \quad6\quad 2\quad 4\quad 9\quad 8\quad 7\quad 1$$and $I$ be the identity permutation. Also, let m be the order of $\sigma$ (i.e. m = min{positive integers $n$ : ${\sigma}^{n} = I$}. Then what is the value of m?

Comment: It might be helpful to write $\sigma$ in cycle notation.

Answer (score 5):

We have

$$\sigma=(1369)(254)(78)=\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3$$
and 
$$o(\sigma)={\rm lcm}(o(\sigma_1),o(\sigma_2),o(\sigma_3))=12$$